# AES_ENCRYPT MySQL Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I hope you can help. I am trying to use the AES_ENCRYPT on my update query but I am unable to get it to work.

I am trying to encrypt the first_name variable but when I run the query it refuses to update the field. When I remove the AES_ENCRYPT method from the update query it works absolutely fine.

My current code looks as follows:

```
if(!define('SALT')) define('SALT','4a7s3n3j93n98lk');

$sql = "UPDATE cases 
    SET first_name=?, 
        last_name=?
    WHERE cases_id=?";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
    AES_ENCRYPT('$first_name','".SALT."'), 
    $last_name,
   $id));
$db = null;
```

Comment: AES_ENCRYPT isn't a php function.

Comment: `if(!define('SALT'))` that should be `if(!defined('SALT'))` as per https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php from https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php *defined() - Checks whether a given named constant exists*.

Comment: Apologies Jon for using the wrong terminology. The question has been edited. Thanks for the input Funk Forty Niner, I will correct the defined named constant to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my AES_ENCRYPT update query issue with the following revision:

```
$encrypt_key = '4a7s3n3j93n98lk';

$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE cases SET 
first_name = AES_ENCRYPT(:first_name, '$encrypt_key'), 
last_name = AES_ENCRYPT(:last_name, '$encrypt_key'), 
WHERE cases_id = :id");

$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();

$db = null;
```